# wubi chown mysql to the /host folder not working

Tags: hosts, chown

I installed wubi in D: driver. Since I want to store mysql database folder in D: driver which has a lot more space than inside wubi. I copy `/var/lib/mysql` to `/host/mysql` then change the database dir in `my.cnf` file to the new location.

After that I use `chown mysql:mysql /host/mysql`, then check `ls /host` and `ls /host/mysql`, the owner of `mysql` and everything inside are still `root:root`.

Anyone has any idea how to change the owner from `root:root` to `mysql:mysql`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this recursively. Therefore, use the `-R` option of `chown`. Use this command to change the owner of every file in that directory to `mysql:mysql`:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /host/mysql
```

From the `man` page of `chown`:

> -R, --recursive
>         operate on files and directories recursively